# How can I collect all ids of elements that have been hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this script to hide dynamically generated rows. Here 'x' is an id of a row. I want to collect all ids which has been hidden. and want to append all the ids in a hidden field.

**JS**

```
function call(x) { 
  var del = $('.' + x).hide();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a  class="" onclick="call(x)">Remove</a><input type="hidden" name="Ids" value="Javascript return ids">
```

Comment: `delete` is a keyword, avoid using it

Comment: thankx arvind.. but still it is not working. i want to store ids as (1,2,3.....).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend marking all the elements that this function has touched.

```
function call( x ){ 
  var deleted_elements = $('.'+ x).addClass( "was_hidden" ).hide();
}
```

Now you can use that class to target all elements that have been hidden with the function:

```
var hidden_elements = $( ".was_hidden" );
```

If you are un-hiding the elements, don't forget to remove that class!

```
$( ".was_hidden" ).removeClass( "was_hidden" ).show()
```

Comment: Note Arvind's comment above. You might want to fix that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have few errors:

```
<a  class="" onclick="call('x')">Remove</a> <!-- in single quotes -->
                           ^-^
```

JS

```
function call(x) { 
  var ids = $('.' + x).hide().map(function(){
    return this.id;//<-- get id
  }).get();
  console.log('ids, ', ids );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function call(x) { 
      var del = $('#' + x).hide(); // Change just '.' to '#'
    }

<a  class="" onclick="call(x)">Remove</a>
```

Just make above changes. And if there is multiple ids with same name then give me full html and js code. You can create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Thnx @Rickyrock This is working fine for html. but when i am using PHP to make it dynamic i am unable to capture all the hidden fields ids.

Comment: Can you please post all HTML structure with PHP? It's not enough to get answer properly.